# .htaccess 301 redirect affecting SEO & google webmaster banned the links

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, google-search-console

At first I must say that I am beginner with .htaccess.

I have a site which is almost one year old and till last week it was working fine. All my threads/posts were indexed in Google Search, and my 80-85% traffic was coming from Google Search. One more important thing is,

```
till last week most of my posts was indexed in google as example.com/any/link/
```

Last week i updated my existing .htaccess file and added below code to the same.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

This redirect is very important for my site due to some plug-ins I am using. This will redirect (301) any request like `example.com` to `http://www.example.com`. so any link of my site on google search listed as `example.com/any/link` will be redirected(301) to `http://www.example.com/any/link.`

4 days back I received a mail from google webmaster team which says like

> Google has detected sneaky redirects  on your site. This means that
>   users visiting your site are redirected to another page or are
>   shown different content. This creates an
>   unexpected experience for Google Search users and violates our
>   Webmaster Guidelines. Therefore Google has prevented the offending
>   pages from showing in search results. This manual spam action has been
>   applied to `example.com/`. To reinstate these pages in search
>   results, remove the spam and file a reconsideration request.

now my question is this google ban due to the 301 redirect i am using ? i think so, because i tested the links from both desktop and mobile devices and there is nothing like a redirect other than this.

if it is then how can i overcome it ? ( considering the fact that this redirect is very important to me, i need to add `http://www.` before any link which misses it )

Comment: did you try resubmitting the sitemap

Comment: i did `fetch & render` my website for re-crawl 2 days ago. didn't help

Comment: I mean by generating a `sitemap.xml` file and submitting that. It would make google bot not see any redirects f all links generated start with `www.`. Also, making sure your websites internal self-links start with `www.` might help

Comment: yes internal links start with `www.` . ok will do that as you said lets see if that helps.

Comment: you can change your prefered domain (www vs non-www) in google search console https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en